# Matrix multiplication with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, tikz-matrix

Using the code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183152/114895) and tedious edits with Adobe Illustrator I managed to produce the following figure

[image]

I'd be interested to see if someone can come up with Tikz code that does the same thing.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: @BambOo I don't have any code except what's in the answer I've linked. I have 0 knowledge about Tikz, so it's difficult for me to even understand this code. This is why I used Illustrator instead.

Comment: Gabriel, I understand that you may begin with tikz, it is quite a powerful tootl but requires a lot of training to get a grip on it. However, if you show at least a very minimal starting point you can draw much more attention to your question. We all started somewhere. If you do not understand something in tikz, you canr refer to the [official documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf). A word search can be very useful, I do this all the time personnaly

Comment: One suggestion: take a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40539/121799), try to modify it and if you get stuck you have something to post here. I guess that then people won't be that reluctant to help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just for fun, an option using matrix,positioning, and fit libraries, to get aligned shapes.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,positioning,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        %Global config
        baseline=0cm,
        >={Stealth[length=7pt,width=13pt]},
        line width=1pt,
        %Styles
        Parenth/.style={
            left delimiter={(},
            right delimiter={)}
        },
        Matrix/.style={
            matrix of nodes,
            font=\small,
            text height=7pt,
            text depth=1pt,
            text width=15pt,
            align=center,
            column sep=8pt,
            row sep=7pt,
            nodes in empty cells,
            %nodes={draw}
        },
    ]

    \matrix[Matrix] at (0,0) (M1){ % Matrix contents 
        7.2 & & & & 3.2 \\
        3.5 & & & & -7.4 \\
        \vdots & $\cdots$ &  & $\cdots$ & \vdots \\
        -1.1 & & & & 4.1 \\
        14 & & & & 19 \\
    };

    \matrix[Matrix,below=0.5 of M1] (M2){ % Matrix contents 
        0 & &1 & & 0 \\ 
        1 & & 0 & & 0 \\ 
        0 & & 2 & & 0 \\ 
        \vdots & $\cdots$ & \vdots & $\cdots$ & \vdots \\ 
        2 & & 0 & & 2 \\ 
        0 & & 0 & & 1 \\ 
        0 & & 0 & & 1 \\ 
    };

    \matrix[Matrix,left=1 of M2] (M3){ % Matrix contents 
        & &\\
        & &\\
        & &\\
        \vdots &  & \vdots \\
        & &\\
        & &\\
        & &\\
    };

    %Put labels in center of some nodes:
    \draw (M1-3-3.center) node[scale=3,transform shape]{H};
    \draw (M3-4-2.center) node[scale=3,transform shape]{W};

    %Hightlight elements 
    \node[draw,inner sep=0,fit=(M1-1-1)(M1-5-1)](HL1-M1){};
    \node[draw,inner sep=0,fit=(M1-1-5)(M1-5-5)](HL2-M1){};
    \node[draw,inner sep=0,fit=(M2-1-1)(M2-7-1)](HL1-M2){};
    \node[draw,inner sep=0,fit=(M2-1-3)(M2-7-3)](HL2-M2){};
    \node[draw,inner sep=0,fit=(M2-1-5)(M2-7-5)](HL3-M2){};
    \node[draw,inner sep=0,fit=(M3-1-1)(M3-7-1)](HL1-M3){};
    \node[draw,inner sep=0,fit=(M3-1-3)(M3-7-3)](HL2-M3){};

    %Delimiters
    \node[Parenth,inner sep=0,fit=(M1)](BM1){};
    \node[Parenth,inner sep=0,fit=(M2)](BM2){};
    \node[Parenth,inner sep=0,fit=(M3)](BM3){};

    % Drawing the arrows.
    \draw[<->]
    (HL1-M1.north west)++(0,0.3) coordinate (temp) 
        -- (temp -| HL2-M1.east)
        node [midway,anchor=south]{$| \text{docs} |$};
    \draw[<->]
    (HL1-M3.north west)++(0,0.3) coordinate (temp) 
        -- (temp -| HL2-M3.east)
        node [midway,anchor=south]{$k$};
    \draw[<->]
    (HL1-M2.south west)++(0,-0.3) coordinate (temp) 
        -- (temp -| HL3-M2.east)
        node [midway,anchor=north]{$| \text{docs} |$};
    \draw[<->]
    (HL1-M1.north west)++(-0.7,0) coordinate (temp) 
        -- (temp |- HL1-M1.south)
        node [midway,anchor=east]{$k$};
    \draw[<->]
    (HL3-M2.north east)++(0.7,0) coordinate (temp) 
        -- (temp |- HL3-M2.south)
        node [midway,anchor=west]{$| \text{V} |$};
    \draw[<->]
    (HL1-M3.north west)++(-0.7,0) coordinate (temp) 
        -- (temp |- HL1-M3.south)
        node [midway,anchor=east]{$| \text{V} |$};


    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a look at the code and get back to you.

Comment: +1. All your answers are excellent. Congratulations to you.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Can you elaborate on what `(HL1-M1.north west)++(0,0.3) coordinate (temp) -- (temp -| HL2-M1.east)` does ? And why it can't be replaced with  `(HL1-M1.north west)++(0,0.3) -- (HL2-M1.north east)++(0,0.3)` ? It's ok if you refer back to the documentation.

Comment: Btw, it seems that Milo got a simpler implementation with `\draw[<->]
    ([yshift=0.5em]M1.north east)--([yshift=0.5em]M1.north west) node [midway,above] {$| \text{docs}`. What do you think about that ?

Comment: Well, I usually avoid the using of shiftings, and because I did not know what can be done with the node names, but if you are going to use the same shifting in both you must do it in the draw statement `\draw[<->,yshift=0.5em] (M1.north east)--(M1.north west) node [midway,above] {$| \text{docs}`; I use a temporal cordinate named arbitrary temp to save the shifted point (Node_name)++(shiftx,shifty) --> saved as (temp) then draw a line to the intersection of (temp) -| Other_node_name), to do the same...

Answer (score 4):

Here is a start. Using my answer from [Is there some way put boxes around matrix elements without too much effort?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445701/is-there-some-way-put-boxes-around-matrix-elements-without-too-much-effort/445703#445703) for the boxes.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing,fit}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrixenv/.style={decoration=brace,every left delimiter/.style={xshift=2pt},every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-2pt}}}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrix/.style={matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells,left delimiter=(,right delimiter={)},inner sep=1pt,row sep=-0.2em,column sep=0.8em,nodes={inner sep=6pt}}}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445703/128068
\newcommand*\mymatrixbox[5][]{\node [fit= (m-#2-#3) (m-#4-#5)] [draw,inner sep=-2pt,#1] {};}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0cm,mymatrixenv]
    \matrix [mymatrix,text width=0.6em,text height=0.8em,align=center] (m)  
    {
    0 & & 1 & & 0 \\ 
    1 & & 0 & & 0 \\ 
    0 & & 2 & & 0 \\ 
    \vdots & \cdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots \\ 
    2 & & 0 & & 2 \\ 
    0 & & 0 & & 1 \\ 
    0 & & 0 & & 1 \\ 
    };

    \mymatrixbox{1}{1}{7}{1}
    \mymatrixbox{1}{3}{7}{3}
    \mymatrixbox{1}{5}{7}{5}

    \draw [latex-latex,thick] ([yshift=-0.5em]m.south east)--([yshift=-0.5em]m.south west) node [midway,below] {$| \text{docs} |$};
    \draw [latex-latex,thick] ([xshift=1em]m.south east)--([xshift=1em]m.north east) node [midway,right] {$| \text{V} |$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice, I'll have a look at the code and get back to you.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a rough proposal:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,tikzmark}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
        \node (a) {$
            \begin{pmatrix}
                7.2 &  &  &  & 3.2 \\
                3.5 &  &  &  & -7.4 \\
                \vdots & \cdots & \tikz[baseline]{\node{\Huge H};} & \cdots & \vdots \\
                -1.1 & & & & 4.1 \\
                14 & & & & 19
            \end{pmatrix}
            $
        };
            \draw[<->] (a.south west) -- (a.north west) node[midway,left] {$k$};
            \draw[shorten >=.5cm,shorten <=.5cm,<->] (a.north west) -- (a.north east) node[midway,above] {|docs|};
        \node[below=1 of a] (b) {$
                \begin{pmatrix}
                    0 & & 1 & & 0 \\
                    1 & & 0 & & 0 \\
                    0 & & 2 & & 0 \\
                    \vdots & \cdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots \\
                    2 & & 0 & & 2 \\
                    0 & & 0 & & 1 \\
                    0 & & 0 & & 1
                \end{pmatrix}
            $
        };
            \draw[shorten >=.5cm,shorten <=.5cm,<->] (b.south west) -- (b.south east) node[midway,below] {|docs|};
            \draw[<->] (b.south east) -- (b.north east) node[midway,right] {|V|};
        \node[left=1 of b] (c) {$
                \begin{pmatrix}
                     & & & \\
                     & & & \\
                     & & & \\
                     \vdots & \tikz[baseline=-.1cm]{\node{\Huge W};} & \vdots \\
                     & & & \\
                     & & & \\
                     & & & 
                \end{pmatrix}
            $
        };
            \draw[shorten >=.5cm,shorten <=.5cm,<->] (c.north west) -- (c.north east) node[midway,above] {$k$};
            \draw[<->] (c.south west) -- (c.north west) node[midway,left] {|V|};
                \draw[xshift=-2.2cm] (-.1,-1.3) rectangle (.6,1.3);
                \draw[xshift=1.7cm] (-.1,-1.3) rectangle (.6,1.3);
                    \draw[yshift=-4cm,xshift=-1.4cm] (-.1,-1.65) rectangle (.22,1.4);
                    \draw[yshift=-4cm,xshift=-.05cm] (-.1,-1.65) rectangle (.22,1.4);
                    \draw[yshift=-4cm,xshift=1.27cm] (-.1,-1.65) rectangle (.22,1.4);
            \draw[yshift=-4cm,xshift=-5.6cm] (-.1,-1.65) rectangle (.22,1.4);
            \draw[yshift=-4cm,xshift=-3.75cm] (-.1,-1.65) rectangle (.22,1.4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

P.S.: The `tikzmark`library didn't work, so I couldn't use the `fit` library.